# How to sum with condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named `pkg_guru`, which has these fields:

```
id, id_pkg, id_penilai, id_guru, id_soal, jawaban, kompetensi
```

in "kompetensi" field, there are four categories: 1,2,3,4

And I want to SUM for each categories, for example:

```
category 1 : total score 10
category 2 : total score 30
etc
```

and display it on the next form..

Can you tell me the code of it?

Comment: GROUP BY, and use CASE in the SUM, e.g. SUM(case when ... then ... end)

Answer (score 0):

You could group on `kompetensi` and sum whatever column contains the score (I'm assuming jawaban in the example):

```
select  kompetensi
,       sum(jawaban)
from    YourTable
group by
        kompetensi
```

Comment: how about the condition? can you give me an example?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "condition"?

Comment: if kompetensi = 1 then sum kompetensi 1... etc

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps you could add some example input data to your question.

Comment: @OryzaSativae This is a very basic SQL problem. The fact that you have not even tried to run the answer shows lack of interest to learn. Learn some SQL, run this answer on your table and see if you get your answer. Else return and update this question with more details. Then someone can answer your problem!